# Why return value is not equal Array?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm doing depth first search but output is not equal Arrays. What is wrong?

```
public static int[] Search (int [][] graph){
        boolean[] visited = {false, false, false, false, false, false};
        int n = 6;
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        Search(graph, visited, n, 0);
        return output.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }

    public static void Search(int[][] graph, boolean [] visited, int n, int i) {
        System.out.print((i )+" ");
        visited[i] = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (!(visited[j]) && graph[i][j] == 1) {
                Search(graph, visited, n, j);
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] graph={{0,1,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0}};

        int [] Searchresult={0,1,4,5,2,3};

    }
```

As you see DFSresult and output are same. Did I make a mistake in return statement?

Comment: Well you are currently comparing this : `[] ?= [0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3]` check your logic. `output` never receive values to put in an array.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DFS(graph)` method returns an empty array:

```
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
DFS(graph, visited, n, 0);
return output.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

You never add anything to the ArrayList that the array is created from.

You probably forgot the step where you pass the `output` list to the `void DFS(int[][] graph, boolean [] visited, int n, int i)` method and add values to it.

```
public static int[] DFS (int [][] graph) {
    boolean[] visited = {false, false, false, false, false, false};
    int n = 6;
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    DFS(graph, visited, n, 0, output);
    return output.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}

public static void DFS(int[][] graph, boolean [] visited, int n, int i, List<Integer> output) {
    System.out.print((i )+" ");
    output.add(i);
    visited[i] = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (!(visited[j]) && graph[i][j] == 1) {
            DFS(graph, visited, n, j, output);
        }
    }
}
```

After making these changes, the output becomes

> 0 1 4 5 2 3 DFS is working correctly